# Make UserControl as Embedded Resource

Tags: c#, asp.net, embedded-resource

I am looking for a way with which I can use User Control as an Embedded Resource in My Project. Is there any way to achieve this or please suggest another way to handle functionality of user control.

Please if you have any example it will be better.

Comment: Create a Server Control instead. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhzc935f.aspx

Comment: @Magnus, original question is about Asp.Net mvc, not WebForms, so Server Controls can't be used for ViewUserControl objects

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov I want to add user control in WebForms Only. Sorry the Question got tagged in ASP.net mvc category.

Comment: oh, ok, then Server Control is good way to go. But it won't allow you to make User Controls. Just usual Controls\WebControls.

Answer (score 0):

For Implementing Embeded user control you have to follow below steps:

Step 1. Create a C# "ASP.NET Empty Web Application" in Visual Studio 2010 or Visual Web Developer 2010. Name it as "CSASPNETAccessResourceInAssembly ". The application need create two projects,  ��CSASPNETAccessResourceInAssembly��, ��CSASPNETAssembly��.

Step 2. Add a user control and a web form page in the project ��CSASPNETAssembly��, this project is the target project, another project will access these resources. For making difference with other pages or user controls, we need add some text and special color border with them.

Step 3. Add a folder with web pages and user controls to ��CSASPNETAccessResourceInAssembly�� project like step 2, we also need add some text and borders. Then we need to add a master page for display the resources of all projects, add a web form page and name it as ��Default.aspx��, and load user controls and links in code behind file. For the normal web page and user controls, we can add the relative path directly, but for the resources of other assemblies, we need add some special information to combine a little complex url string.
The following code is use to add user controls and links in Default.aspx page.

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{ 
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    // Add relative web pages and user controls in assembly and this application. 
    DataTable tab = this.InitializeDataTable(); 
    if (tab != null && tab.Rows.Count != 0) 
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < tab.Rows.Count; i++) 
        { 
            Control control = Page.LoadControl(tab.Rows[i]["UserControlUrl"].ToString()); 
            UserControl usercontrol = control as UserControl; 
            Page.Controls.Add(usercontrol); 
            HyperLink link = new HyperLink(); 
            link.NavigateUrl = tab.Rows[i]["WebPageUrl"].ToString(); 
            link.Text = tab.Rows[i]["WebPageText"].ToString(); 
            Page.Controls.Add(link); 
        } 
    } 
} 


/// <summary> 
/// Initialize a DataTable variable for storing URL and text properties.  
/// </summary> 
/// <returns></returns> 
protected DataTable InitializeDataTable() 
{ 
    DataTable tab = new DataTable(); 
    DataColumn userControlUrl = new DataColumn("UserControlUrl",Type.GetType("System.String")); 
    tab.Columns.Add(userControlUrl); 
    DataColumn webPageUrl = new DataColumn("WebPageUrl", Type.GetType("System.String")); 
    tab.Columns.Add(webPageUrl); 
    DataColumn webPageText = new DataColumn("WebPageText", Type.GetType("System.String")); 
    tab.Columns.Add(webPageText); 
    DataRow dr = tab.NewRow(); 
    dr["UserControlUrl"] = "~/Assembly/CSASPNETAssembly.dll/CSASPNETAssembly.WebUserControl.ascx"; 
    dr["WebPageUrl"] = "~/Assembly/CSASPNETAssembly.dll/CSASPNETAssembly.WebPage.aspx"; 
    dr["WebPageText"] = "Assembly/WebPage"; 
    DataRow drWebSite = tab.NewRow(); 
    drWebSite["UserControlUrl"] = "~/WebSite/WebUserControl.ascx"; 
    drWebSite["WebPageUrl"] = "~/WebSite/WebPage.aspx"; 
    drWebSite["WebPageText"] = "WebSite/WebPage"; 
    tab.Rows.Add(dr); 
    tab.Rows.Add(drWebSite); 
    return tab; 
 } 
}
```

Step 4. Everything is fine, now we can begin to create a custom virtual file system. In the first step, create a class to inherit the VirtualPathProvider class and override some necessary methods, such as  FileExists, GetFile, GetCacheDependency, this class is use to receive and analyse the message that can get the correct resources in a web request.

**The following code is a custom virtual path provider class that can distinguish the ��Assembly/xxx�� folder.**

```
public class CustomPathProvider : VirtualPathProvider 
{ 
    public CustomPathProvider() 
    {  
    } 


    /// <summary> 
    /// Make a judgment that application find path contains specifical folder name. 
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="path"></param> 
    /// <returns></returns> 
    private bool AssemblyPathExist(string path) 
    { 
        string relateivePath = VirtualPathUtility.ToAppRelative(path); 
        return relateivePath.StartsWith("~/Assembly/", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase); 
    } 


    /// <summary> 
    /// If we can find this virtual path, return true. 
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="virtualPath"></param> 
    /// <returns></returns> 
    public override bool FileExists(string virtualPath) 
    { 
        if (this.AssemblyPathExist(virtualPath)) 
        { 
            return true; 
        } 
        else  
        { 
            return base.FileExists(virtualPath); 
        } 
    } 


    /// <summary> 
    /// Use custom VirtualFile class to load assembly resources. 
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="virtualPath"></param> 
    /// <returns></returns> 
    public override VirtualFile GetFile(string virtualPath) 
    { 
        if (AssemblyPathExist(virtualPath)) 
        { 
            return new CustomFile(virtualPath); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            return base.GetFile(virtualPath); 
        } 
    } 


    /// <summary> 
    /// Return null when application use virtual file path. 
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="virtualPath"></param> 
    /// <param name="virtualPathDependencies"></param> 
    /// <param name="utcStart"></param> 
    /// <returns></returns> 
    public override CacheDependency GetCacheDependency(string virtualPath, IEnumerable virtualPathDependencies, DateTime utcStart) 
    { 
        if (AssemblyPathExist(virtualPath)) 
        { 
            return null; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            return base.GetCacheDependency(virtualPath, virtualPathDependencies, utcStart); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Step 5. Then we can create a virtual file class that get the path from virtual path provide class and check the url is available or not, and return the relative assembly��s file stream.
The following code shows how to check the url��s useful information and get the stream of resources.

```
public class CustomFile: VirtualFile 
{ 
    string path 
    { 
        get; 
        set; 
    } 


    public CustomFile(string virtualPath) 
        : base(virtualPath) 
    { 
        path = VirtualPathUtility.ToAppRelative(virtualPath); 
    } 


    /// <summary> 
    /// Override Open method to load resource files of assembly. 
    /// </summary> 
    /// <returns></returns> 
    public override System.IO.Stream Open() 
    { 
        string[] strs = path.Split('/'); 
        string name = strs[2]; 
        string resourceName = strs[3]; 
        name = Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.BinDirectory, name); 
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(name); 
        if (assembly != null) 
        { 
            Stream s = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName); 
            return s; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            return null; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Step 6. At last, you need only register the CustomPathProvider class to the Application_Start event. The provider start to work when you try to run this application.

**The following code is use to register the custom path provider class to Application_Start event.**

```
using System.Web.Hosting;  
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    HostingEnvironment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider(new CustomPathProvider()); 
}
```

Step 7. Build the application and you can debug it.

Comment: hi, i have used above code it's running well but when I published this project and upload to iis , after starting application  iis is unable to find web usercontrols.